# Using google api to create and share a spreadsheet

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a script that I'm attempting to pass data through that would create a google spreadsheet and share it with a group of people. I'm having trouble with an error that is rejecting my permissions, though I don't know why.

I've gone through the google developer console and created a project and enabled both the spreadsheets api and the drive api. I downloaded a single oauth2 set of credentials and named it "credentials.json"

From there I wrote this script based off the google api examples using the v4 sheets and v3 drive versions:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
CREDENTIALS = r'google_api\credentials.json'
TEST_ADD_EMAIL = <the test gmail address>

class GoogleManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sheets_service = None
        self.drive_service = None

    def connect(self):
        store = file.Storage(r'google_api\token.json')
        creds = store.get()

        if not creds or creds.invalid:
            flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CREDENTIALS, SCOPES)
            creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)

        self.sheets_service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
        self.drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    def drive_add_writer_perm(self, fileId, emails):
        def callback(request_id, response, exception):
            if exception:
                raise exception
            else:
                print(f"Permission Id: {response.get('id')}")

        if isinstance(emails, str):
            emails = [emails]
        elif not isinstance(emails, (list,tuple)):
            raise TypeError('Emails must be str or list-like object')

        batch = self.drive_service.new_batch_http_request(callback=callback)
        for email in emails:
            user_permission = ({'type': 'user',
                                'role': 'writer',
                                'emailAddress': email
                                })
            batch.add(self.drive_service.permissions().create(fileId=fileId,
                                                      body=user_permission,
                                                      fields='id'))
        res = batch.execute()
        return res

    def create_new_sheet(self, workbook_name):
        spreadsheet = {'properties': {'title': workbook_name}
                       }
        gSheet = self.sheets_service.spreadsheets()
        newsheet = gSheet.create(body=spreadsheet, fields='spreadsheetId').execute()
        return newsheet
```

From there I run:

```
gmanager = GoogleManager()
gmanager.connect()

new_sheet = gmanager.create_new_sheet('Test Sheet')

sheet_id = new_sheet.get('spreadsheetId')
gmanager.drive_add_writer_perm(sheet_id, TEST_ADD_EMAIL)
```

But I get this error:

```
raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=request.uri).errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1PuxZR0Cx2tGi7c1worVc_Ivj9kZijq_xwwndix6I9as/permissions?fields=id&alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission">
```

Can anyone explain why? What am I doing wrong?

edit: when I go to that link in the exception I'm given this response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

I'm not getting a login screen, what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of playing, it seems that building two services at once is ill advised. I can't explain why, and hopefully someone can, but by building both, and then calling one before the other, the other service is broken.

Changing my code to this works:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
CREDENTIALS = r'google_api\credentials.json'
TEST_ADD_EMAIL = <my_test_email>

class GoogleManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.store = None
        self.flow = None
        self.creds = None

    def connect(self):
        self.store = file.Storage(r'google_api\token.json')
        self.creds = self.store.get()

        if not self.creds or self.creds.invalid:
            self.flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CREDENTIALS, SCOPES)
            self.creds = tools.run_flow(self.flow, self.store)

    def add_writer_perm(self, fileId, email):
        def callback(request_id, response, exception):
            if exception:
                raise exception
            else:
                print(f"Permission Id: {response.get('id')}")

        user_permission = ({'type': 'user',
                            'role': 'writer',
                            'emailAddress': email
                            })
        drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', http=self.creds.authorize(Http()))
        res = drive_service.permissions().create(fileId=fileId,
                                                  body=user_permission,
                                                  fields='id').execute()
        return res

    def create_new_sheet(self, workbook_name):
        spreadsheet = {'properties': {'title': workbook_name}
                       }
        sheets_service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=self.creds.authorize(Http()))
        gSheet = sheets_service.spreadsheets()
        newsheet = gSheet.create(body=spreadsheet, fields='spreadsheetId').execute()
        return newsheet


def main():
    gmanager = GoogleManager()
    gmanager.connect()

    new_sheet = gmanager.create_new_sheet('Test Sheet')
    sheet_id = new_sheet.get('spreadsheetId')

    gmanager.drive_add_writer_perm(sheet_id, TEST_ADD_EMAIL)
```